# What is the proper way to get the folder in which a file resides, given it's file path as a string?

Tags: c++, macos

I'm making a simple `C++` program and am wondering the proper way to accomplish the following.

`argv[1]` is supposed to be the full file path to a file that my program reads

If a second command-line argument `argv[2]` is given, it is expected to be the path to a folder where I'll dump the file my program writes. If no second argument is given (if `argc < 2`), then I'll dump the file my program writes into the same folder from which the inputted file came.

How should I do this? Should I just go through the forward slashes of `argv[1]` until I find the last one? That seems a little sketchy. Is there a more ironclad way of doing this?

Comment: [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) or the upcoming [`std::experimental::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) if your library supports it.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to get the location is get location inside the program through any env variabe if you want to give location while executing progam then you can supply location absolute path of location.